# Creating multiple data frames using same pipes but different columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that I'd like to perform Age and Gender counts for each date and make a new dataframe to be joined together after. The workflow is like this:

```
age_count <- master %>%
  count(Age, Date) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Age, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)%>%
  arrange(Date)
```

The dataframe `master` contains other info such as gender in other columns. The `Date` column is also not unique, so `add_count()` doesn't work. Right now I'm repeating code for each of the columns by changing the column names (e.g. `Age` becomes `Gender`) to come up with these pivots, but I was wondering if it's possible to do this without repeating similar code by using a loop, in case I want to do more of the same pivots for more columns in the `master` dataframe? I'm mainly having issues with the new df assignments.

A snippet of the master dataframe looks something like this:

```
Date <- c("5/21","5/21","5/22","5/22","5/24","5/24","5/24")
Age <- c("70","80","70","70","60","40","40")
Gender <- c("M","M","F","M","F","M","M")
master <- data.frame(Date,Age,Gender)
```

Comment: You could wrap your code in a function and then apply it to multiple columns. If you need help with that please share a little bit of sample data to test the code on, for example `dput(master[1:5, c("Date", "Age", "Gender")]` will give a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows for those three columns---adjust the subset to make sure it illustrates the problem.

Comment: Just added a small example for the master data frame. I would appreciate some help with wrapping it in functions for sure as I'm not very well versed. Thanks!

Comment: What's the output you're trying to get exactly?

Comment: The output for age_count should be a first column "Date" followed by however many unique "Age" columns (e.g., in the example master table there will be 4: 40, 60, 70, and 80.) The "Date" column will be unique, so each row would be a date that has a tally of each age group. I'm doing the same thing for Gender and other parameters (not shown in this example master df) - once I get those I do a bind_cols() call to make a new df basically of counts of each date for each of my specified categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach which nests a call to `purrr::map_dfc` inside `dplyr::across`. It should work for all variables, but we need to convert them to factors first.

```r
library(tidyverse)

master %>% 
  mutate(across(!Date, as.factor)) %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), # uses all variables, expect Date bc its the grouping var
                   ~ map_df(set_names(unique(.x)),
                    function(y) {
                      sum(y == .x, na.rm = TRUE)
                    }))
            ) %>%
  do.call("data.frame", args = .) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

#>   Date Age.70 Age.80 Age.60 Age.40 Gender.M Gender.F
#> 1 5/21      1      1      0      0        2        0
#> 2 5/22      2      0      0      0        1        1
#> 3 5/24      0      0      1      2        2        1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Ah, across() is definitely a really good way of going about this. Works well on my end. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit hacky, because we have to use a `do.call("data.frame")` to convert the `tibble` columns to normal columns, but the variable names are displayed nicely, so its a good workaround I'd say. I'm working on a better programatic implementation for this kind of operation within a package. I will update my answer, once I have a working version.